# Вывод из массива рандомом без повторов

Tags: javascript

есть массив. нужно вывести из него в случайном порядке элементы, но так что бы элементы не повторялись.
помогите плиз. всю голову уже  сломал..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант без перемешивания, наверное неоптимально, что-то думалка не работает

```
function getNextRand(array) {
    var l = array.length;
    if (l < 2) return array.shift();
    var n = parseInt(Math.random() * l),
        ret = array[n],
        first = array.shift();
    array[n - 1] = first;
    return ret;
}
```

[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Fry/)

Answer (score 1):

можно перемешать массив, затем скопировать его копию в второй массив, и выводить фором , может лучше даже с конца массива, удаляя при каждом проходе последний элемент массива arr.slice(0, -1)

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffle(o){ 
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

И потом просто выводим элементы на экран